# OpenCV program compiles but doesn't run

Tags: c++, opencv, runtime-error

I am working on Windows 8 with OpenCV 2.4.13 and MinGW 4.9.
I wrote a simple and small opencv program to check if everything was installed properly. Following is the code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main () {
    printf("in main\n");
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("here\n");
        IplImage * image = cvLoadImage("C:/{...}/test.jpg");
        cvReleaseImage(&image);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with the following command at the command prompt:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -LC:\{...}\opencv\build\x64\vc11\lib -lopencv_core2413 -lopencv_highgui2413 -IC:\{...}\opencv\build\include
```

{...} is the path to the specified folder/file.

This command runs properly and compilation is successful without any errors. However, when I run it with:

```
test
```

`in main` and one `here` gets printed after which I get the error message as 'test.exe has stopped working. Windows is looking for a solution.'

What all I have tried:

1. For installation of OpenCV, ran the downloaded opencv executable file (which extracts all files) and added the system variable OPENCV_DIR and edited the system PATH for location of DLLs (which reside in %OPENCV_DIR%\bin) as per:
   http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#installation-by-using-the-pre-built-libraries
2. Tried adding the required DLLs in the same directory as the .exe.
3. Tried doing the whole thing from vc12 directory.
4. After the error message appears, it gives an option of debugging. On pressing that, the Just In Time Debugger opens up and says 'An unhandled win32 exception occurred in test.exe'. I googled this and tried inspecting the registry key as directed here
   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811191
   but it was already properly set. So, there was nothing for me to change in that.

Nothing is working for me at all. Please let me know if any more information is required. I'm desperately looking for a solution to this.

Comment: Are you sure it is supposed to be `cvReleaseImage(&image);` and not `cvReleaseImage(image);`? What is the value of `image`? Did you maybe get a `nullptr` because the image could not be found or loaded?

Comment: @nwp I just now tried adding an `if..else..` with printfs to check if image pointer was `NULL`, it crashes at `cvLoadImage`, I guess. Nothing after the `cvLoadImage` line prints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might be encountering the same problem, I compiled the program with OpenCV dynamic (`.dll`) libraries instead of the `.lib` files and it ran just fine at runtime for some reason.